# A shift of a trapezoid and a connect to the original

Tags: graphics, geometry

I have:

```
Graphics[{
  Line[{{0, 0}, {30, 0}, {55, 50}, {-25, 50}, {0, 0}}]
  }]
```

Now, I'd like to keep it in place, then shift a copy up and to the right, then connect the four vertices of the first trapezoid with the corresponding vertices of the shifted trapezoid.

Is there a cute way to do this in Mathematica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
l1 = {{0, 0}, {30, 0}, {55, 50}, {-25, 50}, {0, 0}};
t = TranslationTransform[{5, 5}];
Graphics[{Line[{l1, t[l1]}], Line[Transpose[{l1, t[l1]}]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ah, `TranslationTransform` is a much neater idea, of course. :)

Comment: that's definitely the winner!

Answer (score 2):

How cute do you want? Here is what I would do:

```
trapezoid = {{0, 0}, {30, 0}, {55, 50}, {-25, 50}, {0, 0}};
shifted = 20 {1, 1} + # & /@ trapezoid;
Graphics[{
  Line@trapezoid,
  Line@shifted,
  Line@Thread[{trapezoid, shifted}]
}]
```

[image]

The `shifted` is created by adding a fixed offset to each coordinate in `trapezoid`. The connecting lines are created using `Thread` which pairs the corresponding vertices. You could also use `Transpose` for that, but I find that a bit less clear when dealing with lists of more than two dimensions.

You can also do something like this, but I'm not sure if it improves clarity:

```
base = {{0, 0}, {30, 0}, {55, 50}, {-25, 50}, {0, 0}};
trapezoids = {base, 20 {1, 1} + # & /@ base};
Graphics[{
  Line /@ trapezoids,
  Line@Thread@trapezoids
}]
```

Comment: Eh... Now our answers are identical, since you switched to `Transpose`

Comment: @BlacKow fixed ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about cuteness. I made this as an exercise of glueing pure functions.

```
Graphics[(Line /@ Transpose@#)~
      Join~(Line /@ #) &@{#, {#[[1]] + 30, #[[2]] + 20} & /@ #} &@{{0,
     0}, {30, 0}, {55, 50}, {-25, 50}, {0, 0}}]
```

[image]